# XAMPP htdocs folder elsewhere

Tags: apache, xampp

Hey guys I have one folder which I like to keep my backups in its on my Desktop. I use it to backup to the Cloud etc.

My XAMPP site is in c:/xampp/htdocs/mysite

What I want is to have that mysite folder inside my Desktop folder so i can backup it one push /w all my other stuff, I could move the whole XAMPP directory into my Desktop folder but then i need to setup transfer filters so I don't backup all the necessary XAMPP folders .etc

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the  **httpd.conf** file of your apache server and find the settings related to this variable "**DocumentRoot**".

You will find it similar to this.

```
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp/www/"
```

Then replace the current folder path with the path to the folder you needed as the new document root and restart the server.